# Turning MySQL Rows Into Individual Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch, rows

What I need to do is collect each row from my database and put each on into its own array

I thought something like $row[1][1] (e.g. $row[row number][column number]) and I tried this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`;";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$Array = array();

$index = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $Array[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
}

echo $row[1][1];
```

But the echo doesn't seem to work at all and I don't know where it goes wrong? I've been trying to fix it for around 2 hours and have finally given up

Comment: maybe , reading your own code , `$Array[1][1]` would reveal som'n.  An IDE with debug capability would certainly render thing obvious.

Comment: Use `print_r($Array[0]);` - you are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` which will mean each row will have a list of fields keyed by the name of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, since you're using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` it will loop over all rows of table fields and the variable `$row` will have the array associated with the current row if you put it in a `while` loop. 
If you want to access that outside of the `while` loop you can use your method of creating another array above. You still need to reference the field by name though in this case:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$Array = array();
?>
<pre>
<?php   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Array[] = $row;
}
print_r($Array[1]['your_field']);
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already stated that you get an associative array (indexed by column name) if you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

You can get an integer-indexed array if you use [mysqli_fetch_row($result)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) instead, or if you use [mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

You can also simplify your code so you don't have to write your own while loop if you use [mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_NUM)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). That function returns an array of arrays, just like you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `fetch_all()`. For example:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` ";
$result = $link->query($query); // If variables are involved you must use prepare/bind_param/execute

$matrixOfRowsAndCols = $result->fetch_all();

echo $matrixOfRowsAndCols[1][1];
```

The default fetch style is numerical array, so you will get a numerical column index as well as numerical row index. No need for any loops.